# GTK Maximizing a Form c++

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3, glade

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I have a small GTK 3.0 Form I am trying to get to maximize on first startup. I later want to get this into a Full GLADE project, but first I'm just trying to get this to maximize to full screen.

The commented sections are what I have tried to no avail.
Nothing works and it throws compiler errors, can anyone help me in my endeavor?

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

 GtkWidget *window;

 gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

 window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
 gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Center");
// gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 230, 150);
 // gtk_window_fullscreen(GTK_WINDOW(window);
// gtk_window_fullscreen(GtkWindow *window);
gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
gtk_widget_show(window);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
  G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  gtk_main();

   return 0;
 }
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should quote compile errors in full in your post. But anyway, maximise != full-screen; please determine which you want/need and clarify, in addition to adding all the errors. For instance, `gtk_window_fullscreen(GTK_WINDOW(window)` should just work, so it's not at all clear why it didn't for you.

Comment: also, i just realised this is more like C and gtk. not realy gtkmm, which should be used ideally with C++

Answer (score 1):

Use [`gtk_window_maximize(GtkWindow *window)`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-maximize):

```cpp
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

   GtkWidget *window;

   gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

   window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
   gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Center");

   gtk_window_maximize(GTK_WINDOW(window));

   gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
   gtk_widget_show(window);

//...
 }
```

Note that you *can* call it before showing the window. Doc:

> Asks to maximize window , so that it becomes full-screen. Note that **you shouldn’t assume the window is definitely maximized afterward**, because other entities (e.g. the user or window manager) could unmaximize it again, and not all window managers support maximization. But normally the window will end up maximized. Just don’t write code that crashes if not.
>    It’s **permitted to call this function before showing a window**, in which case the window will be maximized when it appears onscreen initially.
>   You can track maximization via the “`window-state-event`” signal on `GtkWidget`, or by listening to notifications on the “`is-maximized`” property.

**Suggestion**: Use [**gtkmm**](https://www.gtkmm.org/en/) with C++

Example with gtkmm:

```cpp
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  auto app =
    Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv,
      "org.gtkmm.maximize.base");

  Gtk::Window window;
  window.maximize();

  return app->run(window);
}
```